# Agility Pack Select SingleNode @id contains or @id is like

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectsinglenode

Is there any functionality in Html Agility Pack `SelectSingleNode` to let me search similiar IDs?

Looking for something like

```
string str = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[@id **contains** 'id_']/span/text()")
                 .InnerText;
```

or

```
string str = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[@id **startsWith** 'id_']/span/text()")
                 .InnerText;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are XPath functions `contains()` and `starts-with()`, exactly as you wish. Example usage of those functions :

```
string str1 = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[contains(@id, 'id_')]/span/text()")
                  .InnerText;
string str2 = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[starts-with(@id, 'id_')]/span/text()")
                  .InnerText;
```